# Out of range error using a for loop over Swift array's indexes

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, indexing

I am getting an "out of range error" when iterating through an array using a `for` loop, and I can't figure out why.

```
var oddNumbers: [Int] = [1,3,5,7,9]
for number in (0...oddNumbers.count+1) {
    print(oddNumbers[number])
}
```

Comment: `oddNumbers`'s index needs to be 0 to `oddNumbers.count - 1` (inclusive). Writing `for number in (0...oddNumbers.count+1)`, `number` can be greater than that.

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 values in your array, but your loop runs from 0 to 6, so you end up with:

> Index 0: 1
>
> Index 1: 3
>
> Index 2: 5
>
> Index 3: 7
>
> Index 4: 9
>
> Index 5: Error

Better approach is to use the array count and run the loop until one number less than that (to account for the indexing numbering). Note the use of `..<` instead of `...` and `count` instead of `count + 1`

```
var oddNumbers: [Int] = [1,3,5,7,9]
for number in (0 ..< oddNumbers.count) {
    print(oddNumbers[number])
}
```